# PageSpeed=noscript redirects in loop if not preceded by slash

Tags: nginx, redirect, mod-pagespeed

I have a great problem with Nginx and PageSpeed and his **noscript** feature.
If the `GET` parameter is not preceded by a slash, the server redirects in loop the page, concatenating a thousand of same PageSpeed parameters in the URL query.

Look at this:

With the slash before the question mark the page loads:
http://www.architetturaecosostenibile.it/architettura/progetti/?PageSpeed=noscript

Without the slash the page redirect in loop:
http://www.architetturaecosostenibile.it/architettura/progetti?PageSpeed=noscript

The returning URL is http://www.architetturaecosostenibile.it/architettura/progetti?PageSpeed=noscript/&PageSpeed=noscript/&PageSpeed=noscript/&PageSpeed=noscript/&PageSpeed=noscript/&PageSpeed=noscript/&PageSpeed=noscript/ ...

The problem **does not** occur for other GET parameters:
http://www.architetturaecosostenibile.it/architettura/progetti?PageSpeed=foobar

This is mistery. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apache:

```
ModPagespeedSupportNoScriptEnabled false
```

Nginx:

```
pagespeed SupportNoScriptEnabled false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a Joomla SEF extensions. Solved with its update.